# Make a header/text line between field rows in an SSRS Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I want a line between the package_notes and parent_line_pack_notes lines that is virtually just one big text box (i don't want the column lines) where I can type a boldfaced header or note that is the same every time, and still able to toggle visibility.  How can I do that?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a text parameter for your note that you want to include - let's call it `Note`. In the first cell on this line enter the following expression:

```
=Parameters!Note.Value
```

On the Properties window set `Font`-`FontWeight` to `Bold`.

With the first cell highlighted, hold down Shift and click in the last cell on that row. Right-click and select `Merge Cells`.

When you run the report you will be able to type the note into the parameter and it will appear on that line in bold without column lines.

Comment: In my case, it won't be a parameter, but your answer still did the trick! (It's the same note everytime, so it's just a constant text box.  Thanks man!